Struggling making built-in modules
I am designing two modules - one is class and second is device driver. My problem is both .ko modules at the end are not built-in and not called for probing the device in the device tree - when I insert class and then driver in using insmod, only then device file is created.
I put the files into the package/kernel/mypackage directory, with Makefile containing
define KernelPackage/mypackage
 ...
 FILES:= $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/mydriver.ko $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/myclass.ko
 AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoLoad,30,mypackage,1)
 ...
endef

and then have src/ directory with source files and Makefile containing
obj-m += myclass.o
obj-m += mydriver.o

When I run make V=s package/kernel/mypackage/{clean,compile} I see "need-built-in=1" on the screen, when I just run make V=s I do not see it.
Next, if I change obj-m to obj-y things stop compiling at all, process is complaining about missing .ko files (which are really missing in the work directory).
What do I do wrong?
Update: while sawdust is definitely correct, the cause of my issue was
AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoLoad,30,mypackage,1)

which contains package name mypackage, while is must contain module/driver to autoload
AUTOLOAD:=$(call AutoLoad,30,mydriver,1)


"I put the files into the package/kernel/mypackage directory" - So your source code for your module is out-of-tree, i..e. separate from the kernel source code tree.  Source code for a module that is in-tree, i..e. part of the kernel source code tree, can be built as a loadable module (i.e. a separate .ko file) or statically linked into the kernel image (aka "built-in"). But out-of-tree code (such as your module) can only be built as a loadable module. Your effort to build it into the kernel will be futile. "What do I do wrong?" - You've put your files in the wrong place.

@sawdust please move it into the answer and I will accept it. Did not try it yet (struggling with other issues) but more than sure you are right. There's also an "autoprobe" option (instead of "autoload") within the makefile to try.


I put the files into the package/kernel/mypackage directory

So your source code for your module is out-of-tree, i..e. separate from the kernel source code tree.
Source code for a module that is in-tree, i..e. part of the kernel source code tree, can be built as a loadable module (i.e. a separate .ko file) or statically linked into the kernel image (aka "built-in").
But out-of-tree code (such as your package for a module) can only be built as a loadable module. Your efforts to build it into the kernel will be futile.

What do I do wrong?

You've put your files in the wrong place.
You could merge your code into an appropriate sudirectory in a copy of the kernel source tree, then define a new CONFIG_MYDRIVER build symbol for your module, and modify the appropriate Kconfig and Makefile files to support your new module.
Or leave your code out-of-tree and build a loadable module. Then properly install the .ko file to automatically load your module during boot (i.e. after the rootfs is mounted and maybe before userspace is started); see https://lwn.net/Articles/740455/ and https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Module-HOWTO/#AUTOLOAD. If using an ARM SoC, then be aware of a properly written Device Tree that needs to specify the driver, e.g. see Driver code in kernel module doesn't execute?.
